# AngularJS: bo-bind of bindonce and the translate filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bindonce

I'm using `angular 1.2.25`, `angular-translate 2.0.1`, `angular-translate-loader-static-files 2.0.0` and `angular-bindonce 0.3.1`.

What I want to do is translating a static translation key with bindonce. So I got this code snippet:

```
<div bindonce>
  <div bo-bind="'TEST' | translate"></div>
</div>
```

As result of this snippet the translation key is displayed instead of the translation. If I'm using now `ng-bind` instead of `bo-bind` everything works just fine:

```
<div>
  <div ng-bind="'TEST' | translate"></div>
</div>
```

I have stepped through with the debugger and it seems like the translate filter doesn't exist when `bo-bind` is executed.

Is there any way I can use this one time binding in combination with angular-translate?

[Here is a plunker replicating my issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/vb1ShUHGqGvKtVonKgrf?p=preview)

Comment: It might be worth filing a bug in the bindonce repository for this. The `README` in the repo specifically states that filters can be used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div bindonce="languages">  <div bo-bind="'TEST' | translate"></div></div>
```

in controller just set scope "language" = true when angular-translate build complete. I think you should use rootscope for saving "language"